# Rename Stored Procedures that start with a certain prefix

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a large number of Stored Procedures that need to be renamed.  Luckily, they all start with the same prefix e.g. `spPortalxxxxxx`

I need to rename them e.g. `v11_spPortalxxxxxx`

Is there anyway to rename all of the Stored Procedures in one go rather than having to do each one manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could be tempted to `SP_Rename` but that can be one the worst things to do, since it doesn't update `sys.procedures` see [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/28/sql-server-renaming-stored-procedure-does-not-update-sysprocedures/)

An approach I could think of is creating a query that drops the old ones and recreate them with the new name.

```
SELECT 'drop procedure ' + OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) + ';
go
' + 
REPLACE (OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID), 'spPortal', 'v11_spPortal') + '
go
'
FROM sys.procedures
```

This query will update also any call to inside the definition...

**I think that you are adding this for versionning, if so you would need to add a `WHERE OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) LIKE 'spPortal%'`**

Don't forget that you will need to apply `GRANT` as needed.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is to create the rename statements by a Sql query. Then copy and paste the query result to new query window to execute

```
select 

'sp_rename ''' +[Routine_Name]+''','''+'v11_'+[Routine_Name]+''''

FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[ROUTINES]
WHERE [ROUTINE_TYPE] = 'PROCEDURE'
and [Routine_Name] like 'spPortal%'
```